# The sea is ruining my framerate, is there anything I can do to increase my FPS?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've got a nice little coastal fort going but even on a fairly small embark spot it's killing my frame rate.

If I built floor over the sea with stone, would that be likely to increase the frame rate as the game would no longer have to simulate waves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe this will help. Even if covering the ocean with floor prevents the waves from being displayed, the simulation will still calculate them (the DF wiki [says](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Ocean) waves "seem to move independently of constructed tiles like walls and floors.").

Hopefully you can find something on the [framerate wiki page](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Framerate) that helps.

Comment: What about draining the sea into an aquifer? I'm sure it'd absolutely murder my frame rate during the process, but is that even close to a viable option?

Comment: @Aslum -[This](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/40d:Ocean#Draining_the_ocean) article agrees that it will kill your framerate, and unfortunately will not drain the ocean, as it is replenished very quickly from the map edge.